# How to force splinefun values to be positive?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

I have generated a ggplot using values from splinefun, but the values aren't supposed to be negative within the area near 0, as shown in the figure below.

I wonder how to force the values in splinefun to be 0 when they are negative? Thank you!

```
sigma <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
sigma <- matrix(sigma,ncol=1)

myFunc_sig <- function(sigma){
  exp(-2/sigma^2)
}

output_sigma <- apply(sigma, 1, myFunc_sig)
spl_fun <- splinefun(sigma, output_sigma)

ggplot(data.frame(x = sigma, y = output_sigma), aes(x, y))+ 
  stat_function(fun = spl_fun, color = "orange")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image: The image is in this link]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can require the spline function to be monotonic by specifying `method="monoH.FC"` or `method="hyman"` in `splinefun`. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

myFunc_sig <- function(sigma){
  exp(-2/sigma^2)
}

sigma = 0:12
output_sigma <- myFunc_sig(sigma)
spl_fun <- splinefun(sigma, output_sigma, "monoH.FC")

ggplot(data.frame(x=sigma,y=output_sigma),aes(x,y)) + 
  stat_function(fun = spl_fun, color = "orange") +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.02)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

And with `method="hyman"` the plot looks like this:

[image]

If, for some reason, you did want to make artificial adjustments to the values, you could calculate them outside `ggplot` and plot them with `geom_line`. For example:

```
x = seq(min(sigma),max(sigma),length=100)
y = spl_fun(x)

# Set negative values to zero
y[y<0] = 0

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y), colour="orange") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=sigma, y=output_sigma), aes(x,y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.02)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really solves my problem!